# debug_print_backtrace() to String for log-file

Tags: php, debugging, logging

I have a problem. I would like to log the backtrace in a specific case in a log-file. `debug_print_backtrace()` builds a correct string for my purposes but `debug_print_backtrace()` prints the trace on the screen instead of returning it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use another function.  [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) returns an array that you can loop through, format and save:

```
$data = debug_backtrace();
```

Or use output buffering for the formatted output string:

```
ob_start();
debug_print_backtrace();
$data = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 20):

It's possible to do it with even less code, actually.  Avoid the overhead of buffering with...

```
$error_string = (new Exception)->getTraceAsString();
```

That gives you the exact same output as `debug_print_backtrace()` stored to the `$error_string` variable.

And if you want to get more information for a more valuable stacktrace (line numbers, local object vars, etc.), try...

```
$error_string = print_r($e->getTrace(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the answer given by [@HoldOffHunger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430549/holdoffhunger), the following would have been sufficient for logging purpose:

```
$this->log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
```