# SQL not Inserting using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code sending data from a form to an SQL database:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include 'includes/db_connection.php';

if(empty($_POST)){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else{
    try {
        $dbconn = OpenCon();
        $fname = $_POST['fnameInput'];
        $sname = $_POST['snameInput'];
        $sex = $_POST['sexInput'];
        $dob = $_POST['dobInput'];
        $schoolID = $_SESSION['school'];
        $sqlstmnt2 = 'INSERT INTO students (`firstName`, `surname`, `dob`, `gender`, `schoolID`) VALUES (:firstName, :surname, :dob, :gender, :schoolID)';
        $stmtUsr2 = $dbconn -> prepare($sqlstmnt2);
        $stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':firstName', $fname);
        $stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':surname', $sname);
        $stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':dob', $dob);
        $stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':gender', $sex);
        $stmtUsr2 -> bindValue(':schoolID', $schoolID);
        $stmtUsr2 -> execute();
        // redirect to pupil's profile
        header("Location: pupilprofile.php");
        die();
        } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "DataBase Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "General Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

My database table is structured as with studentID being a primary key auto incrementing and all fields apart from dob as text (dob is set as datetime)

The form which is sending the data looks like this:

```
<form action="registersubmit.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="fnameInput"><div id="erfirstname"></div><br>
    Surname: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="snameInput"><div id="ersurname"></div><br>
    Sex:      <select id="sexInput" name="sexInput">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select><div id="ersex"></div><br>
    DOB:    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dobInput"><div id="erdob"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="pupilRegSubmit" value="Register" onclick="if(validatePupilReg()) this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

I'm not getting a PDO error but the data is not inserting in to the table. I'm thinking that it might be something to do with the date picker not matching with the data type in SQL but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried without the `ob_start()` to see if anything is output.

Comment: try ```print_r($stmtUsr2->errorInfo());``` after ```execute()``` to find out the insertion error

Comment: If your database table has studentID as an autoincrement, and you are trying to insert with that value supplied, its a good chance you will get an error about value already exists in table. When doing an insert on a table with autoincrement, its best not to pass that column in the insert statement... let it do its job. Make sure your PDO is configured to toss exeptions too `$your_pdoobject->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: OK I have the following error message which I'm guessing is something between the data type of the Datepicker and the data type of the SQL field. thisArray ( [0] => 22007 [1] => 1292 [2] => Incorrect datetime value: '08/10/2020' for column 'dob' at row 1 )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Get MySQL Errors in PHP**

You can know if the MySQLi statement succeeded by printing the results of `$statement->execute()`.  To quote the POD...

> Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. (Source: [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php))

If it returns `TRUE`, then maybe there is a different problem going on than the statement failing.

You can also see the results of MySQL statement with [**`error()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [**`errno()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php), from the MySQLi package in PHP.  You don't list it in your code, but you must have defined `$dbconn` in a way like this...

```
$dbconn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

After executing with `$stmtUsr2 -> execute();`, try running this code...

```
print_r($dbconn->error);
print_r($dbconn->errno);
```

**Your Specific Case**

Change your datepicker's format to match MySQL's insert format.

```
$(selector).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});
```

**More Help**

I have another answer on getting more debug info here: [debug_print_backtrace() to String for log-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19644447/2430549).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not getting anything printing from the errors. dbconn works OK because I have other code using it successfully

Comment: @user1480135 Thanks for getting back to me, what is returned by `OpenCon();`?  Also, maybe try printing the results of $statement->execute()?  If it's 0, it failed (which I assume is the case), but if it reports 1, maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: Weirdly I'm not getting a 0 or a 1 by typing $result = $statement->execute() and then echo $result

Comment: @user1480135 : Can you disable this line `header("Location: pupilprofile.php");`?  Otherwise the page will simply redirect before you can see anything.

Comment: The error is showing as thisArray ( [0] => 22007 [1] => 1292 [2] => Incorrect datetime value: '08/10/2020' for column 'dob' at row 1 )

Comment: @user1480135 : Now that you know how to detect that you have a MySQL error, you should check how to format your insert values for date values.  You need datetime values to be in the form of "2020-08-10 00:00:00", etc..  But that's a different question!  Think you can mark this as the correct answer, if it's helpful?  I also added datepicker formatting info.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

into to the Datepicker function to match the format with the MySQL date time field

Comment: So, I helped you debug the problem, how to get MySQL errors, and I got the error and the solution for you.  Wouldn't it have seemed more cooperative to have marked my answer as correct, instead of reposting it as your own answer?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen your amendments when I found my answer elswhere

Answer (score -3):

IS onclick="if(validatePupilReg()) this.form.submit() Working?

Use AJAX / JQuery for form submission:

```
$('form').on('click', function() {  

    var form_input = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax_calls/xxx",
        data: form_input,
        success: function(this_result){
```

Comment: It must be working because I've had PDO error outputs previously from dodgy syntax

Comment: @henry551: How is using AJAX/JQuery (a front-end language) supposed to solve an error with MySQL (a backend language) not executing?